# Customize a <select> tag in LWC

Tags: salesforce-lightning, lwc, salesforce-communities

I want to customize the  tag of the LWC. I have made the background transparent. My background image is dark. So, I want my text to appear as white so that it is visible. Also, while selecting the options, I want the dropdown menu to be transparent with white text.
Below are the issues am facing-

1. I have mentioned value = "Select unit" in the select tag. However, it appears blank in the web window. It should mention 'Select unit' when the page is loaded.[No text visible in the select field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8lI6.png)
2. When the dropdown(all options) in opened, it has background as white instead of transparent. Is there a way to make it transparent?[Unable to make dropdown transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll3Fr.png)

Can someone please help me with this?
Thank you!

I tried below code in HTML and CSS-

Below is my HTML code for the select component-

```
<Lightning-layout class="slds-align_absolute-center">

                <lightning-layout-item>
                    <lightning-input id="heightInput" value="Enter height" class="inputItemsClass slds-m-right_small"></lightning-input>
                </lightning-layout-item>

                <lightning-layout-item>
                    <lightning-select id="selectHeightUnit"  value="Select unit" options={heightUnitList}
                        class="selectHeightUnitsClass slds-m-left_small"></lightning-select>
                </lightning-layout-item>

            </Lightning-layout>
```

Below is the CSS code-

```
.selectHeightUnitsClass {
    --slds-c-select-color-background: none;
    --slds-c-select-color-background-focus: none;
    --slds-c-select-text-color-focus: black;
    --slds-c-select-text-color: white;
    --slds-c-select-text-color-focus: white;
}

.inputItemsClass {
    --slds-c-input-color-background: none;
    --slds-c-input-text-color:white;
}
```

The background of the dropdown is still white. I want it to be transparent.